# bulk change sas project code nodes directory

Tags: sas, sas-macro, enterprise-guide

I have a SAS Project(SAS Enterprise Guide version 7.15) and all the sas code nodes are currently saved on directory location,

'C:\Users\SAS\Prod\SASCode'. I am taking a backup of this project to the Dev area and I would like to save the sas code nodes to the following Dev location 'C:\Users\SAS\Prod\SASCode'. Is there a way I can bulk change the location of all this sas code nodes to the above Dev location instead of going into individual sas codes nodes and change it one by one which is of course very time consuming process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Should be possible, since EG-Project are basicly ZIP-files containing the various elements.
One of these Elements is the file "project.xml" wich contains the references to external code-files.
Replacing this references with the new location should solve your problem.

Comment: Hi Michael thanks for your answer however, I cannot locate this file in my project project.xml. Do you know where should I be looking to find this file?

Comment: Short Version: Unzip your .egp file, there you find project.xml and all kinds of other stuff e.g sas code and logs of internaly in the project safed code nodes. For external sas code you find reference to that .sas files like link inside project.xml. More detailed information was kindly provided by Richard in his answer.

Answer (score 2):

Enterprise Guide project files are really a collection of files within a zip archive that has a file extension .egp instead of .zip.

Suppose your code nodes are shortcuts to files in the operating system, in a single folder, and you want to change where those files are located.  The targets of the shortcuts are stored in the egp file in a contained file `project.xml` as project metadata.  `project.xml` is a UTF-16 encoded file and the shortcuts are xml data within a `<FullPath>` node.  The xml file is very systematic and can be text processed with out needing to do a full xml parsing.  The goal is to replace the old path with the new path for data in FullPath nodes.

Powershell is a very potent tool for Windows scripting and can be used to tear apart the project file, modify the paths and reassemble the pieces back into an .egp project file.

Consider this powershell script:

The code nodes for the original project were shortcuts to files in C:\Zeus\sources.  Suppose those sources were copied or moved to C:\Olympus\sources.  The code nodes of an updated EG project have to be modified to point to the new location.

```
$egpIn  = 'C:\Q1\Zeus.egp'
$egpOut = 'C:\Q2\ZeusModified.egp'

$oldPath = 'C:\Zeus\sources'
$newPath = 'C:\Olympus\sources'

Copy-Item "$oldPath\*.sas" -Destination $newPath

$oldLandmark = [regex]::Escape('&lt;FullPath&gt;' + $oldPath)
$newLandmark =                 '&lt;FullPath&gt;' + $newPath

$workingFolder = 
[System.IO.Path]::Combine(
    [System.IO.Path]::GetTempPath(),
    [System.IO.Path]::GetRandomFilename()
)

[System.IO.Compression.ZipFile]::ExtractToDirectory($egpIn, $workingFolder)

Get-ChildItem $workingFolder *.xml -recurse |
  Foreach-Object {
    $fileContent = ($_ | Get-Content -Encoding Unicode)

    $fileContent = $fileContent -replace $oldLandmark, $newLandmark

    [IO.File]::WriteAllText($_.FullName, ($fileContent -join "`r`n"), [System.Text.Encoding]::Unicode)
  }

if (Test-Path $egpOut) 
{
  Remove-Item $egpOut 
}

[System.IO.Compression.ZipFile]::CreateFromDirectory($workingFolder,$egpOut)

Remove-Item $workingFolder -Recurse
```

Comment: Awesome  I think our OPS will like this little shellscript ☺️ Thx.